# How to getText() from the input field of an angularjs Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I have my DOM as below,

```
<input class="k-textbox ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="text" placeholder="" ng-blur="controller.isDirty=true" ng-change="controller.isDirty=true" ng-model="controller.model.value" ng-required="controller.model.required" ng-disabled="controller.model.readOnly" ng-focus="controller.showFieldHistory(controller)" disabled="disabled">
```

I want to `getText()` from the above input tag. I tried below methods, but since this is a `JSapplication` I am unable to `getText`. Though the text is not visible in the `DOM` but it is visible for the user in the `UI`.

```
List<WebElement> values = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='controller.model.value']"));
    for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)
    {
        String theTextIWant = values.get(0).getAttribute("ng-model");
        System.out.println(theTextIWant);

    }
```

Below is the output I get when the above code is executed.

> controller.model.value
>
> controller.model.value
>
> controller.model.value

From the output I can say that it just gets the value present inside the attribute "ng-model" but not the actual text that is visible in the `UI`. Please advice how can I get the text that is visible in the `UI`.

Expected Text:

> 9161
>
> Wesley
>
> Choate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `ng-model` as an attribute, It's just use to getting the model value from the controller at runtime and set to this value to the `input`. So in this reason you are getting the `ng-model` property instead of real value.

Actually `input` element contains their value in `value` attribute, So you should try as below :-

```
List<WebElement> values = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='controller.model.value']"));
for(WebElement el : values)
{
  String theTextIWant = el.getAttribute("value");
  System.out.println(theTextIWant);
}
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Excellent :)This Helped:) Thank you So Much :) Happy for this :)